# plugin: rewrite rules are lost when WP updates

Tags: plugins, rewrite-rules

I'm developing a plugin, and noticed that my custom rewrite rules are lost after WP updates its core.

It's no big deal, it works again if I disable/reactivate my plugin.

But since I would like to share the plugin on the WP repo at the end, I would like to fix this bug.
Can someone help ?  Here's how my code works.  I guess there is something that is incompatible with WP updating.

```
class WP_SoundSystem {
    public static function instance() {

            if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
                    self::$instance = new WP_SoundSystem;
                    self::$instance->setup_globals();
                    self::$instance->includes();
                    self::$instance->setup_actions();
            }
            return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct() { /* Do nothing here */ }

    function setup_globals() {
        //...
    }
    function includes(){
        //...
    }
    function setup_actions(){
        // activation
        register_activation_hook( $this->file, array( $this, 'activate_wpsstm'));

        // deactivation
        register_deactivation_hook( $this->file, array( $this, 'deactivate_wpsstm'));

        //...

    }
    function activate_wpsstm() {
        $this->debug_log('activation');
        $this->init_post_types();
        $this->add_custom_capabilites();
        $this->init_rewrite();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    function deactivate_wpsstm() {
        $this->debug_log('deactivation');
        $this->remove_custom_capabilities();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    /*
    Hook for rewrite rules.
    */
    function init_rewrite(){
        $this->debug_log('set rewrite rules');

        //files included in includes() above will hook on this to add rewrite rules
        do_action('wpsstm_init_rewrite');
    }
}


function wpsstm() {
    return WP_SoundSystem::instance();
}

wpsstm();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be only adding rewrite rules on activation only, which means that if rewrite rules are flushed for any reason after that, then your rewrite rules are probably being removed. `add_rewrite_rule()` should be hooked on `init`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, it seems to work ! So it should be hooked on 'init' and not on the activation hook, is that it ?